# Use of word “HOW” for exclamation or praise

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, pronouns, exclamations

Can I use the word “how” for praise in this way:

> How they move!

I want to say that how beautifully they move. Is this a correct sentence?

Comment: Yes, "How they move!" would be short for "How beautifully/quickly/smoothly/exotically they move!" with the precise adverb depending on context.

Comment: _How_ is of course only for adverbs; _what_ is for nouns - _What a horse!_

Comment: Great. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The normal structure of an exclamatory sentence with 'How' is :

> (1) How + adjective

e.g., *"How beautiful!"*  *"How nice!"*

> (2) How + Adjective/Adverb + Subject + Verb

e.g., *"How happy (Adj) we were there!"*

*"How beautifully (Adv.) they move!"*

However, you can omit this adverb and say :

> "How they move!"